# Find radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ when $a_n = \frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series

> Find radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ when $a_n = \frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}$.

I am posting this question to verify if my work and reasoning is correct.
Using the divergence test, we have

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n| &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{4^n+3_n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n^2}{4^n}}{1+\frac{3n}{4^n}} \\
&= \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{n^2}{4^n}\bigg)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{3n}{4^n}\bigg)} \\
&= \frac{0}{1} = 0
\end{align}

Since the limit converges to 0, then the radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: No, it is false. You should use the ration test.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah .Typo. You meant the ratio test.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$|a_n|=\frac{n^2}{4^n(1+\frac{3n}{4^n})}\sim \frac{n^2}{4^n}=b_n$$

$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\frac{4^{n+1}}{4^n}$$
$$=4$$

Comment: Why is the ratio b_{n}/b_{n+1} instead of b_{n+1}/b_{n} here?

Comment: @EvanKim To get direct Radius, without inversing.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want, by Cauchy-Hadamard, $r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{n^2}{4^n+3n}}}=4$.